# how fill a list of on class in another class by linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

i want to fill an object that contain a proprty that is a list of an other class. my problem is that how to initialized the proprty that is list of other class. here proprty "images" is a list of class CenterShopImage.

```
    {    
       ID = c.ID,
       address = c.address,
       category = new Model.CenterShopCat
       {
           ID = c.CenterShopCat.ID,
           name = c.CenterShopCat.name
       },
       floorNumber = c.floorNumber,
       images = new List (CenterShopImage) 
       {
           //what should i do here?????
       },
   };
```

thanks.

---

har07 and mjshaw thanks for your answare but i dont know how many CenterShopImage exist!
class Centershop has a list proprty. it is list of CenterShopImage class. so there is a relation between them. each CenterShop has some image. now i want to select images that has relation to the centerShop so there is a foreach for all CenterShopIamge that select some of them that their id is equal tu the centerShopImageID. please help me.

Comment: what is the definition of images?? Is it List<CenterShopImage> images= new List(); ?
Also what is the source of images ? is it another list or what ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on your requirement. If you don't need to set anything, simply remove that part :

```
images = new List<CenterShopImage>()
```

or use [another constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that accept `IEnumerable<CenterShopImage>` if you have initial collection of `CenterShopImage` to add :

```
images = new List<CenterShopImage>(myInitialCollection)
```

If you want to add new items to the list instead of ready to add collection, you can use collection initializer syntax :

```
images = new List<CenterShopImage>()
                {
                    new CenterShopImage
                        {
                            propertyA = "value1"
                        },
                    new CenterShopImage
                        {
                            propertyA = "value2"
                        },
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

I may be misunderstanding, but I believe you are asking how to initalise a list, without the typical "new List()". try the following. I'm assuming CenterShopImage is the type:

```
{
    ID = c.ID,
    address = c.address,
    category = new Model.CenterShopCat
    {
        ID = c.CenterShopCat.ID,
        name = c.CenterShopCat.name
    },
    floorNumber = c.floorNumber,
    images = new List<CenterShopImage>() 
    {
        new CenterShopImage{...},
        new CenterShopImage{...},
        ...
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply select the desired type off of the desired property of "c".
I do not know what type of images that "c" holds or how you create CenterShopImage off from that type, but in this example I assume that you have a CenterShopImage constructor that accepts the c type as argument.

```
{
   D = c.ID,
   address = c.address,
   category = new Model.CenterShopCat
     {
       ID = c.CenterShopCat.ID,
       name = c.CenterShopCat.name
     },
   floorNumber = c.floorNumber,
   images = c.Images.Select(img=>new CenterShopImage(img).ToList()
};
```